# Mongoose pluralization rules not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Reading up on the mongoose it appears that if I declare a mongoose model like this:

```
var User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)
```

Then mongoose will create a collection called "users" (with an 's').

However, I have already manually created a collection called "Regions" in mongo. When I try to declare my mongoose model, it looks like this:

```
var Region = mongoose.model('Region', regionSchema)
```

But then when I try to return all objects using Region.find(), zero results are returned.
So I then tried:

```
var Region = mongoose.model('Regions', regionSchema)
```

And this also returned zero results.

In the end I had to do this:

```
var Region = mongoose.model('Region', regionSchema, 'Results')
```

If mongoose has pluralization rules, how come I still need to pass in the collection name in order for it to find the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Mongoose both pluralizes the model name and converts it to lower case.  So with a model name of `'Region'` it was looking in the `regions` collection.

So you'd need to provide an explicit collection name in the `model` call (like you show), but with a collection name of `'Regions'`:

```
var Region = mongoose.model('Region', regionSchema, 'Regions')
```